# How to start eclipse with different version of Java?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have here a computer (Windows XP) with java 1.4 and java 1.6 (I don't know why there is 1.4 on this system, probably they forget to uninstall it). Here is also Eclipse Helios.

Now if I want to start eclipse I get the message that Java 1.4 is too old. Huh? I have here also 1.6, Eclipse should start with 1.6
I checked the current Java Home via cmd

```
java -version
java version "1.4.2_03"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_03-b02, mixed mode)
```

Ok so somehow 1.4 is the standard java here. Fine, let's change standard java to 1.6 (because it's installed, so it should work). But wait, this is not working I don't have the rights to change that. Cannot change any standard java path. So what can I do? I figured out, that I can bypass the Eclipse message if I edit `eclipse.ini` the line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.4` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5` But at the end I'm using this eclipse with Java 1.4, and who knows what bugs or problems I'm getting with this. I have the path to java 1.6 , can I use this and start Eclipse, how? Any ideas?

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler is it not working for you?

Comment: Sure, but this is then only for my new project right? Not for the Eclipse IDE for themselve. So Eclipse is still usign 1.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the `-vm` option to **eclipse.ini**:

```
-vm
C:/path/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javaw.exe
```

It has to be on 2 separate lines and it has to be added before `-vmargs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the build path

```
Go to Eclipse(mac) / Window(for windows)

->Preferences
->Java

->Installed JREs 

->JAdd the jdk/jre library you would like to add.

->click ok (Done)
```

Then the jdk is configured for the completed eclipse workspace.

You Can change the jdk for the individual project using the build path configuration.

*To do that  :*

Select the project ,right click

```
->Choose the java Build Path.

->JRight hand side of the pane click the "Add Library"

->Choose "JRE system library"
->Select "Alternate JRE" (There u can see the list of the installed/configured JRE).

->Click Finish
```

Let know if still the problem exists.